# WPF Prism 4 Unit Testing

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, moq, prism-4, icollectionview

I have been using Prism 4 to create a composite wpf application, now I want to begin to test the app. using unit testing and moq, I have worked trough the StockTrader RI sample and tried to build my application as close to the RI implementation as i could, i did not use the Controller and Presentation parts to keep things simple, thus just having a View a ViewModel.

I am a bit lost on how to test my ViewModels and CollectionViews in them, is there some tutorial on unit testing in Prism4 that you are aware of just to show the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the tests that come with Prism 4. They actually test the viewmodels in their code so you can use them as an example. For testing of collectionviews you may find this interesting http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2009/02/11/collectionviewmodel.aspx.

Good luck!